# Need to hide rows of a table depending on the permission

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that is being use to hold link and image buttons that link the user to other pages on a web site. I want to hide some of these rows depending on the permission the use has. Right now I have:

```
 // Disable buttons if user does not have admin security level
    if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A")
    {
        linkbtnNewEmployee.Visible = false;
        imgbtnNewEmployee.Visible = false;
        linkbtnViewUserActivity.Visible = false;
        imgbtnViewUserActivity.Visible = false;
        linkbtnEditEmployees.Visible = false;
        imgbtnEditEmployees.Visible = false;
        linkbtnManageUsers.Visible = false;
        imgbtnManageUsers.Visible = false;
    }
```

which will hide the links and buttons, but the table rows still exist. So I have a row or 2 of space between links. I have tried naming rows and using the "rowToHide.style.display = 'none';" command which does not work because it will not recognize the row. The row id shows up in the source code fine, and I use the same ID in the command. Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In markup add an Id for the `<tr>` and `runat="server"` tag , like this:

```
<tr id="rowToHide" runat="server>
   <!-- Contents here -->
</tr>
```

And in the code set the visible property to false, like this:

```
// Disable buttons if user does not have admin security level
if (Session["SecurityLevel"] != "A")
{
    rowToHide.Visible = false;
    linkbtnNewEmployee.Visible = false;
    imgbtnNewEmployee.Visible = false;
    linkbtnViewUserActivity.Visible = false;
    imgbtnViewUserActivity.Visible = false;
    linkbtnEditEmployees.Visible = false;
    imgbtnEditEmployees.Visible = false;
    linkbtnManageUsers.Visible = false;
    imgbtnManageUsers.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: thank you. Was on the right track, just not all the way there.

Comment: Yes, I also think you were almost there :-)